# vue drag resize plugin по touch разрешить переход по ссылке

Tags: javascript, vue.js, touch-event

Есть небольшой проект с [vue-drag-resize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-drag-resize) плагином:

[**codesandbox.io**](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-u657r?fontsize=14)

```
<VueDragResize class="red" :isActive="true" :isResizable="false" :isDraggable="isDraggable">
  <h3><a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Hello World!</a></h3>
</VueDragResize>
```

Click по ссылке срабатывает, а вот touch - нет!

**Question:** Как разрешить переход по ссылке, когда драг не активирован?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <button v-on:click="isDraggable = !isDraggable">
      <span v-if="isDraggable">Close</span>
      <span v-if="!isDraggable">Open</span>
    </button>

    <VueDragResize   class="red" :isActive="true" :isResizable="false" :isDraggable="isDraggable">
      <h3><a  @touchstart="setTime"  @touchend="goTo" href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Hello World!</a></h3>
    </VueDragResize>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import VueDragResize from "vue-drag-resize";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    VueDragResize
  },
  data() {
    return {
      isDraggable: false,
      index: false,
    };
  },

  methods: {
    setTime(){
      this.index = new Date().getTime();
    },
    goTo(e){
      const time = new Date().getTime();
      const b = time - this.index;
      if (b > 200){
        this.index = 0;
        return;
      }
      const href = e.target.href;
      if(href){
       window.open(href)
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

По какой причине не совершается переход, я ответить затрудняюсь. Скорее всего, это связапно с внутреней реализацией плагина

Comment: Интересная реализация!!! СПАСИБО!!!!